# What is the meaning of な＋ほう

Tags: adjectives

I have had a conversation with a Japanese person and I asked the question

> 幸せですか？

The reply was:

> 幸せ**なほう**だと思います

I have seen ほう used in the same context as より when comparing two things but I've not seen it attached to a な type adjective top describe a state of being.  Could anyone help me with this grammar point please?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61945/9831 See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70649/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23883/9831

Comment: I dont think so because this question refers to the speakers state of being rather than a direct comparison of things.  Also, the thing being compared is implied as far as I can tell.

Comment: Actually https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61945/meaning-of-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7 is quite close as it speaks of the meaning as "relatively"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of ほうなんで?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61945/meaning-of-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7)

Answer (score -1):

ほう means "direction" in this context, and can use the kanji 方.