# 方 as a noun with a relative clause. What does it mean?

Tags: words

Today I encountered this sentence:

> その都市の治安はいい[方]{ほう}です。

The general meaning is simple: "The city is safe".

However, what does [方]{ほう} mean in this sentence? Is there an implicit comparison? (ie, "The safety is the best aspect of the city") Does it simply mean "side"? (ie, "Safety is a good aspect of the city").

Thanks.

Comment: What about just a semi-literal rendering? _"The [civic order / public safety] of the city is on the good side."_

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61945/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23883/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70649/9831

Comment: Those links were very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed an implicit comparison, though not with other aspects of the city but rather with other *cities*. I'd say a better translation would be "That city is on the safer side" or "that's one of the safer cities."

Comment: I see. Thank you!